# Mock Service with SoapUI

Tags: java, unit-testing, groovy, mocking, soapui

I created a mock service in SoapUI, with the following code:

```
def requestMethod = mockRequest.getMethod()
log.info "mockRequest.method: " + requestMethod

if (requestMethod.toString() != "GET")
{
log.info "dispatch:Status 405"
return "405 - Method Not Alowed"
}

def acceptEncodingHeaderList = mockRequest.getRequestHeaders().get("Accept-Encoding")
log.info "AcceptEncoding Header List: " + acceptEncodingHeaderList

if(!acceptEncodingHeaderList.contains("gzip, deflate, br") ) {
log.info "dispatch:Status 406"
return "406 - Not Acceptable"
}

def data = setData()
log.info "data:" + data

if(!data.contains("bscs") )
{
log.info "dispatch:Status 400"
return "400 -Bad Request"
}
log.info "dispatch:ok "
return "200 - OK"

def setData() {
def request = mockRequest.getHttpRequest()
def buffer = new StringWriter()
def reader = new LineNumberReader(request.getReader())
def line
while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {buffer.append(line)
buffer.append(System.getProperty("line.separator"))}
def data = buffer.toString()
return data
}
```

The method `reader.readLine()` is returning a null value on the requests after the first one. The other variables and methods in `setData()` are returning values normally.

I tried using `read(char[] cbuf, int off, int len)` instead of `readLine()` and `BufferedReader` in `LineNumberReader` place.